# Function for folium not showing any error on Shapelets-platform

Tags: python, pandas, function, widget, folium

I was trying to create a a dashboard on Shapelets platform, where I would switch from point to cluster of points when pressing a button, I can have the location of the specefic restaurant in that area.

I started ploting the map of the localisation, I then created a function that would plot the point on the folium map when I press the button, then create the buttonb, place the widgets, bind everything and then register the data app.

I don't have any error in my code, it is running perfectly but, when I am pressing the button, nothing is happening.

```
#this is the wrong answer 

import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import folium
from shapelets.apps import DataApp, FoliumChart

rest = pd.read_csv('/restaurant/cluster.csv')

m = folium.Map(location = [25.761681
    ,-80.191788])
# Create a data app
app = DataApp("folium")
# add the points from rest to the map
for index, row in rest.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([row['latitude'], row['longitude']], popup=row['name']).add_to(m)


# add the cluster from rest to the map
def add_points(rest: DataFrame)-> FoliumChart :
    marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(m)
    for index, row in rest.iterrows():
        folium.Marker([row['latitude'], row['longitude']], popup=row['name']).add_to(marker_cluster)
    return app.folium_chart(title='Folium Map', folium=m)

button = app.button(text="Add points")
app.place(button)
folium_chart = app.folium_chart(title='Folium Map', folium=m)
folium_chart.bind(add_points, papa_person, triggers=[button] )
app.place(folium_chart)

app.register()
```

can someone help me please? that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are having an issue on the function it selves, what you are returning is the folium chart on the data app, whereas in the function you are trying to add clusters to the chart. I try with a fix to return a different map directly such as:

```
def add_points(papa_person: DataFrame)-> FoliumChart :
    m = folium.Map(location = [25.761681,-80.191788])
    for index, row in papa_person.iterrows():
        folium.Marker([row['latitude'], row['longitude']], popup=row['name']).add_to(m)
    return app.folium_chart(title='Folium Map', folium=m)
```

This works for me on version 2.0.82, with a random data generated by me.